# GNU toolchain (newlib): compatibility between toolchain versions (undefined symbol __ctype_ptr__)

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, gnu, newlib

Having here a **project** that is **using** some **external GNU-toolchain built libraries** (provided externally, without source-code). I'm compiling an **application** for embedded systems (**FreeRTOS** specifically), so I **use newlib**.

I **initially tried** using this toolchain https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.4-2019.02/aarch64-elf/
but that failed because of (among others) these **linker errors**:

```
undefined reference to `__ctype_ptr__'
```

It seems that this symbol **should be defined by libc**. Going into the **newlib sysroot**, specifically in this case the **sysroot-newlib-linaro-2019.02-aarch64-elf\usr\lib** directory, **tried to find __ctype_ptr__ in libc.a**:

```
aarch64-elf-nm -C --defined-only -g libc.a | grep __ctype_ptr__
```

No output, so **this libc** indeed **does not define __ctype_ptr__**.

Continuing by **taking a look into the library** that **needs the symbol**, a **notepad++ edit revealed** this among the mangled text:

```
/opt/gcc-linaro-5.4.1-2017.05-x86_64_aarch64-elf/aarch64-elf/libc/usr/include/machine
```

Which means this **library was built** using the **5.4.1 aarch64-elf toolchain** version and **I was trying to use version 7.4** since **I need newer C++ standard support**.

**Downloaded the 5.4.1 version** as well (sysroot only): https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/5.4-2017.05/aarch64-elf/

Again, going into the 5.4.1 **sysroot-newlib-linaro-2017.05-aarch64-elf\usr\lib** directory this time:

```
aarch64-elf-nm -C --defined-only -g libc.a | grep __ctype_ptr__
```

finally reveals:

```
0000000000000000 D __ctype_ptr__
```

which means that indeed the **5.4.1 newlib libc** exports this symbol.

Questions:

1. **Why** this **incompatibility** between the 2 versions? What category do these kind of changes belong to? Where can I find more detailed information about changes like these and the reasons they are there?
2. **Am I forced to use the old version** because those libraries were built with it? Is there no way to use the newer version instead? **How are these situations usually handled**?

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue ? I'm stuck on a similar issue

Comment: Hi @SalmanAzmat. I don't remember exactly, but I think I (unfortunately) resorted to using the older toolchain. I don't think I found a satisfying answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

**`_ctype_ptr_`** is simply a pointer to `_ctype_` which is a 128 byte table
containing a bitset used by the ctype.h functions like `isalpha`.
The functions will take a character as a parameter, and will use the
character as an index into the `_ctype_` array.
A mask is applied to the read value, and if non-zero the function returns "true"

You can worst case define your own

```
extern const char _ctype_[];

const char* __ctype_ptr__ = _ctype_;
```

If `_ctype_` is reported undefined by the linker,
you may have to define it in the linker

```
ctype                   = _ctype_;
```

and in the source code.

```
extern const char ctype[];

const char* __ctype_ptr__ = ctype;
```